# C File Parsing Issue

Tags: c, file, parsing

I have a file to read in that is in a format like

3%6%1

5%3%0

4%9%2

I need it in some format where I can save the separate fields from each line, like I suppose 
I can make a typedef SOMETHING with SOMETHING.num1 = 3, SOMETHING.num2 = 6, SOMETHING.num3 = 1

Here's what I have so far:

```
#define BUF 128 
#define LINES 100 

char line[LINES][BUF];

FILE *input = NULL; 
int i = 0;
int total = 0;

input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
while(fgets(line[i], BUF, input)) 
{
  /* get rid of ending \n from fgets */
  line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
  i++;
}

total = i;

printf("ORIGINAL READ:\n");

for(i = 0; i < total; ++i)
{
  printf("%s\n", line[i]);
}

printf("\nPARSED:\n");

char  *token;
char parsed[LINES][BUF];

for(i=0; i<total; i++)
{
  token = strtok(line[i], "%");

  while(token != NULL)
  {
    strcpy(parsed[i],token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "%");
  }
}

for(i=0; i<total; i++)
{
  printf("%s\n",parsed[i]);
}
```

The problem is when I print out the values in my parsed array, it seems to only have the last value of each line, (ie for the sample ^ it would output 1,0,2). I'm new to C programming, how can I go about this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `scanf("%d%%%d%%%d", &a, &b, &c)`?

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do with each token you get from the `while(token != NULL)` loop. What do you want to do with these tokens? Right now, as you say, you're overwriting the `parsed[i]` buffer with each one, so when you run out of tokens `parsed[i]` contains the value of the last token.

Comment: regarding this line: line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0'; strlen() returns the index to the last char before the string terminator, so the line should be: line[i][strlen(line[i])] = '\0';

Comment: this line: char parsed[LINES][BUF]; only allocates one entry for each line in the input file. then this line: strcpy(parsed[i],token); keeps overlaying that same line until the file line is completely parsed.  suggest: 1) use a much shorter BUF as the lines are no where near 128 bytes long. 2) modify the allocation for parsed[][] and modify the strcpy line  so there is room for 3 entries from each line in parsed and strcpy places the tokens in the right entries in parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using `i` to index your parsed numbers, but `i` is also your line index.  You need a separate index to keep track of the numbers you have parsed.

```
int numberCount = 0;

...
    strcpy(parsed[numberCount++],token);
...

for(i=0; i<numberCount; i++)
    printf("%s\n",parsed[i]);
```

Comment: of course, this will overrun the parsed array unless the array is also changed to contain 3 times as many entries.

Comment: Good point.  But really, there's no guarantee that `LINES` (100) will be enough for the number of lines or that `LINES*3` (300) will be enough for the number of parsed numbers (if there are more than 3 numbers on a line for example).  It would be better if he checked against the array bounds everywhere he writes to an array.